# unable to grab the contents from mongodb using underscore

Tags: mongodb, underscore.js

Im trying to pluck / grab the values corresponding to tName from mongodb but i get undefined for it.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var _ = require('underscore'); 
var colors = require('colors')

console.log( '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'.white);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log(' db opened');
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');

var trendSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    tName: String,
    tName_h: String,    
    region: String
  });




var Trend = mongoose.model('Trend', trendSchema);

Trend.find(function(err, trends) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  // console.dir(trends);
  console.log(' trends  ==', trends);
  var plucked =  _.pluck(trends, 'tName');
  console.log(' plucked -----> ', plucked);
});
```

here is the output for it:

```
plucked ----->  [ undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined ]
```

if i replace tName with        var plucked =  _.pluck(trends, '__id');  I get correct result.

example:

var plucked = _.pluck(trends, '_id');
console.log(' get keys ='.red, plucked);

---- output ----

```
get keys = [ 54763e406cfdacf577335e97,
  54763e406cfdacf577335e98,
  54763e406cfdacf577335e99,
  54763e406cfdacf577335e9d,
  54763e406cfdacf577335e9b,
  54763e406cfdacf577335e9c,
  54763e406cfdacf577335e9a,
  54763e406cfdacf577335e9e,
  54763e406cfdacf577335ea0,
  54763e406cfdacf577335e9f ]
```

but for followign code:

```
var plucked = _.pluck(trends, 'tName');
console.log(' get keys ='.red, plucked);
```

output :

```
get keys = [ '#5HSledgehammerSpy',
  '#MTVStars',
  'Anderlecht 1-0 Galatasaray',
  '#MilliLiderErdoğan',
  '#MalmoeJuve',
  'Basel 0-1 Real Madrid',
  '#AFCvBOR',
  'Ludogorets 1-2 Liverpool',
  'DoisMesesPerina',
  'Dimite Ana Mato' ]
```

Comment: Your Trend document in the collection doesn't have a property named `tName`, and so does your schema not reflect it. So why are you accessing a property which you have defined to be non-existant?

Comment: corrected it , but its not the issue.

Comment: Does `_tName` work ?

Comment: it didnt work before but now its workign.. thanks.